# run cron at last day of the month using node cron

Tags: node.js

I am using node cron to run the cron every last day of the month

```
var job = new CronJob('01 01 12 * * *', function() {
    //my function to do job
 }, function () {

 }, true);
```

so what time I should set so that the script run every last day of the month

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The simplest method actually to run the cron at 00:01 the next day of the month, and to use `0 0 1 * *` But if you insist on running it on the last day you will need to check in your script.

Use the following js snippet;

```
const today = new Date();
const tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

if (today.getMonth() !== tomorrow.getMonth()) {
  // run your cron job
}
```

so you can program your cron to run daily but the if will guard to execute it only when it is the last day of the month.

Comment: Thanks!! I think thats the only way I can implement it

Comment: To run the job on daily basis according to Alex answer, we can set cron job to be
`'59 23 * * *'` (last minute of the day)